# I have a problem fetching data from an API and rendering in React. I think my issue is related to my useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have managed to fetch data from my local host using axios successfully. My data base which I am fetching data from, contains the code bellow:

```json
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "json-server",
      "text": "typicode"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "json-server",
      "text": "typicode"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I attempt to utilize `useEffect` to assign the object with `id = 1` to my `useState` variable `selectData`, it doesn't seem to function as expected. Consequently, my web page becomes unresponsive, displaying the message 'Loading...' indefinitely.

Here is the code from react:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const Teste = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  const [selectData, setSelectData] = React.useState(null);

  const get = async () => {
    await axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/posts")
      .then((response) => setData(response.data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    get();
    data.forEach((element) => {
      if (element.id === 1) {
        setSelectData(element);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <section>
      {selectData !== null ? (
        <div>
          <h1>{selectData.title}</h1>
          <div>
            <p>{selectData.text}</p>
          </div>
          <button>Atualizar</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        "Loading..."
      )}
    </section>
  );
};
```

I believe that the error is inside the `useEffect` hook. I have tried changing my code inside the `useEffect` but I didn't have success.

Answer (score 3):

the `get` function is an **async** function and the output of it is a promise. in the `useEffect`, you are traversing the `data` object immediately after calling the `get()`. here the data is still `[]` because the `get` function hasn't finished the loading of the data and setting it to the `data`.
you can move the `forEach` section to the `get` function:

```
const get = async () => {
  await axios
    .get("http://localhost:5000/posts")
    .then((response) => {
      setData(response.data);
      response.data.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.id === 1) {
          setSelectData(element);
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

or as a better approach you can define another `useEffect`, dependent to the `data` object and do the `forEach` section inside of it:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  get();
}, []);

React.useEffect(() => {
  data.forEach((element) => {
    if (element.id === 1) {
      setSelectData(element);
    }
  });
}, [data]);
```

Comment: Thnaks a lot SeyMi, it worked. I used your first solution.